# Origin of the phrase ''Respect,man/bro. ''?

Tags: etymology, slang, colloquialisms, speech, phrase-origin

[Respect bro](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Respect%20bro)!! , you never hear anything like ''Fear, man'' or ''honesty, man.'' used in the same sense, its interesting.

Comment: You do hear _kudos_, _props_, _congratulations_, etc., though. It’s the same thing; there’s just an understood “I offer you my…” or “You have my…” that’s left out because it’s not necessary to say it.

Answer (score 1):

The Green’s Dictionary of Slang suggests that the expression originated in the black communities and  is from the ‘90s:

[Respect:](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/5s2qorq)

> (W.I./UK/US black teen) a phr. used to accord the subject the respect they have earned on the basis of earlier positive or praiseworthy actions; also used as a greeting.
>
> - 1991    [UK]    Reeves & Mortimer Vic Reeves Big Night Out n.p.: *Yo! Respect, Dennis!*
> - 1997    [UK]    C. Newland Scholar 46: *Respec’ cuz, for that ironin’ lick.*

Comment: Yes, and it is still very much in use!